# Need to fetch panoramio user info using google api php client library

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, panoramio

I need to fetch panoramio user info using google api php client library. Can somebody guide me how it is possible using google api php client library? One more thing want to confirm that
is panoramio userid (not username or email id) same as google userid? Since i am using google php api for sign in to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Panoramio is not yet integrated with all the other Google APIs, so you can't access it using the *google-api-php-client library*. They however have 2 public APIs (i.e. without the need to authenticate) that you can use:

- The [Widget API](http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/api.html#toc) for e.g. including photos using JS
- The older REST [Data API](http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html) for quering image metadata in JSON format

Note that both are restriced to 100000 queries/day.

The Panoramio and Google user IDs are **not** correlated.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch panoramio userinfo such as userid, birth date, full name, country, state, city from any api by providing users panoramio email-id and password? I am aware with your mentioned apis which are used for fetching photo details uploaded by user on panoramio.

Comment: Simply said: no. Panoramio does not Provider an authentication API and is not yet supported by Google's OAuth.

Comment: www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=20&minx=-180&miny=-90&maxx=180&maxy=90&size=medium&mapfilter=true. This link is used to fetch all photo details uploaded by user if i pass the panoramio userid in set parameter of url. Thats why, i required panoramio userid once the user sign in to my application. So, it will fetch the photo details of logged in user. Is there any different way to achieve this kind of functionality? @jan

Comment: You can only ask the user to provide his ID or a link to his profile page, where you could extract the ID, manually. He could then of course also use the ID/profile page of somebody else.

Comment: but the requirement of my application is that user should get photo details from his panoramio account not the other user photo details. Thats why i need to authenticate his panoramio account. So is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: There is currently no way to achieve the functionality you require, as I already pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Just one more info i need to know that how to fetch details using photo id or photo url eg. http://www.panoramio.com/photo/1289207. We can fetch photo details using panoramio userid that i know but same thing i need to do using photo id or photo url by an api.

Comment: As this is also not supported by their API, your only way to do that would be to parse the HTML source code of some `http://www.panoramio.com/photo/PHOTO_ID`  page for the link to the user profile page, extract the user ID, request all photos related to this user ID using the Data API and then check the result for the metadata of that specific picture.

Comment: It would be kind of you to mark my answer as accepted, as I think it took everything into account that you asked for in your original post (though it probably was not the answer you hoped for). If you still have any questions/issues feel free to submit a new question to SO.